# Docker For Windows - Java app deployed on a container gets a connection refused error when calling another java app deployed on another container

Tags: spring, docker, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, docker-for-windows

I was using an old version of Docker Toolbox for Windows so I uninstalled it and installed the latest stable Docker for Windows.

I have two Java applications running on its own containers:

- Application1:    http://archimedes1:8761
- Application2:    http://archimedes2:8762

**Dockerfile** used in both apps:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD archimedes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms750m -Xmx750m"
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

I modified my Windows **/etc/hosts** to make archimedes1\2 map 127.0.0.1 (with the previous Docker Toolbox it mapped 192.168.99.100):

```
127.0.0.1           archimedes1
127.0.0.1           archimedes2
```

This is how I start the containers (notice the use of --add-host to make the containers aware of the host names):

```
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=archimedes1" -p 8761:8761 --name archimedes1 --add-host archimedes1:127.0.0.1 --add-host archimedes2:127.0.0.1 -d storyteller/archimedes 
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=archimedes2" -p 8762:8762 --name archimedes2 --add-host archimedes1:127.0.0.1 --add-host archimedes2:127.0.0.1 -d storyteller/archimedes
```

This **worked with Docker Toolbox** but since I installed Docker for Windows the containers, when contacting with each other show a Connection Refused error. In this case archimedes2 tries to call archimedes1:

```
2017-01-25 13:10:27.406 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.MonitoredConnectionManager  : Get connection: {}->http://archimedes1:8761, timeout = 200
2017-01-25 13:10:27.406 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : [{}->http://archimedes1:8761] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 1000
2017-01-25 13:10:27.406 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : No free connections [{}->http://archimedes1:8761][null]
2017-01-25 13:10:27.406 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Available capacity: 500 out of 500 [{}->http://archimedes1:8761][null]
2017-01-25 13:10:27.406 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Creating new connection [{}->http://archimedes1:8761]
2017-01-25 13:10:27.407 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.MonitoredConnectionManager  : Released connection is not reusable.
2017-01-25 13:10:27.407 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Releasing connection [{}->http://archimedes1:8761][null]
2017-01-25 13:10:27.407 DEBUG 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2017-01-25 13:10:27.407 ERROR 5 --- [t_archimedes1-2] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Network level connection to peer archimedes1; retrying after delay

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48) ~[eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116) ~[eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:71) ~[eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:187) [eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**I start a sh into the container and ping archimedes1 from archimedes2's container and it DOES answer**.

```
-> docker exec -it archimedes2 sh
/ # ping archimedes1
PING archimedes1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
```

However if I do a **telnet** it gets a connection refused:

```
docker exec -it archimedes2 sh
/ # telnet archimedes1 8761
telnet: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

If I do the telnet against the own container it works:

```
C:\Users\jinga4x>docker exec -it archimedes2 sh
/ # telnet archimedes2 8762
```

What's going on here?

**UPDATE:**

I have also tested this: **starting archimedes1 as a normal Java application on Windows and archimedes2 in the container**.

**Archimedes1** can contact **archimedes2** but **archimedes2** gets the **connection refused** when it tries to connect archimedes1.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is my `docker network inspect bridge` info:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "546e7a5ef627c8d23e8ffdc05911fcae096167a359701fa4ee08ada0f7e1ae7f",
        "Created": "2017-01-25T11:09:27.651777Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "58634d0c4430895cf0dfbee294c3ea75ca38921441684d614a670421661eb628": {
                "Name": "archimedes2",
                "EndpointID": "b2f40396b4c0f8210ca667d93c7d787296f3dad2d0eb295c31d4f01bfe3b39e1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "85f70520ad900e729944dc768f8c6951e9221650269b5669a2d0269506a4c16b": {
                "Name": "archimedes1",
                "EndpointID": "651bf095eed639ecc61a24ffdaf2130bddd338f38f42f47a6c54b460c3a979ab",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**archimedes1 container ifconfig:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:13158 (12.8 KiB)  TX bytes:345156 (337.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:3200 (3.1 KiB)  TX bytes:3200 (3.1 KiB)
```

**archimedes1 cat etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1       archimedes1
127.0.0.1       archimedes2
172.17.0.2      a8045a473784
```

**UPDATE 3:**

The containers can access each other using the internal Private IPs, but not the public one (127.0.0.1).

**UPDATE 4:**

I started a proxy monitoring archimedes1:22233 and sending it's traffic to archimedes1:8761. archimedes2 tries to comunicate through the proxy but no traffic reaches it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct IP address, you need to use `docker-machine ip`.

For the new Docker for Windows for Windows 10, get the container IDs with `docker ps` and then look for `IPAddress` in the output of `docker inspect $CID` (`$CID` == the container ID to inspect).

Background: Docker can't run containers on Windows. Docker is a pure Linux software. It needs a running Linux kernel to work. The workaround used by the Docker for Windows guys is to install a virtual machine (VirtualBox) on your computer which simulates a whole PC - including network cards, hard disk drives, CPU and everything. Newer versions of the software use Hyper-V which is similar.

Inside of that virtual PC, a complete Linux is installed plus Docker. The Windows tools will connect to that virtual PC to talk to the Docker running inside.

Actually, the address `127.0.0.1` will not leave the container - it won't even mean "the virtual PC inside of which Docker is running". Ping of course works because every computer responds to the address `127.0.0.1` - that doesn't mean it's the same computer you think it should be.

**[EDIT]** The file `/etc/hosts` looks wrong:

```
10.0.75.1       archimedes1
10.0.75.1       archimedes2
```

Those are two different containers; they should have different IP addresses.

I think you have a typo in your `docker run`. `--add-host archimedes2:10.0.75.1` should be `--add-host archimedes2:10.0.75.2`

Comment: Hi Aaron, I am running `docker-machine ip` but get `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists`. How can I know my machine's name?

Comment: Try `docker-machine ls` to get a list of all machines. The error is weird, though; the installer creates the `default` machine.

Comment: In the Docker for Windows Settings -> Network I see Internal Virtual Switch: 10.0.75.0. If instead of using 127.0.0.1 I use 10.0.75.1 the apps are accessible via browser but still can't communicate between themselves

Comment: Maybe you're referring to the previous Docker for Windows version. This one doesn't even run on Oracle's VirtualBox...

Comment: A switch is a component which connects two computers. You need the IP addresses of the containers themselves. Which DfW are you running?

Comment: I haven't used DfW in a while; it seems they replaced the technology under the hood to support Windows 10. Try `docker inspect $CID | grep IPAddress` ($CID is the container ID which you get from `docker run` or `docker ps`; you may have to replace `grep` with the respective Windows command to search in text files).

Comment: Just executed it. archimedes1 has 172.17.0.2 and archimedes2 has 172.17.0.3. The problem is that since they seem to be assigned dynamically I would have to update etc/hosts every time I launch the processes. In the previous DfW they shared the ip 192.168.99.100

Comment: Calling from the browser  172.17.0.2:8761 doesn't answer. 10.0.75.1:8761/ does respond

Comment: hehe, I didn't realize...Anyway, any clue why this isn't working? BTW, thank you for answering.

Comment: I'm not sure. Have a look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: Thanks, that way the resolve each other. BUT, since the assignment of the URLs comes from the start order of the apps, I can't assure that those will always be their IPs, if archimedes2 starts before 1 it would be 10.0.75.1. With the former docker toolbox all containers used the same IP 192.168.99.100 so I didn't have this problem. Any idea how to work this out?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an out of the box solution with pure docker. Most solutions use a third container which is started first. The startup scripts determine it's IP address and pass that to all the other containers. This third container runs a service which registers names and IP addresses of all services. It's a service broker and configuration supplier.

Comment: Forget my previous comment, the problem persists. the containers don't see any 10.0.75.x address. I'll think about your idea of using another container as index, but seems weird that containers don't see the windows network...

Comment: 10.x.x.x is also a private network but so is 192.168.x.x. The virtual switch should be configured to let the containers see each other but maybe you need a special option to make that happen. Did you read the Docker networking guide? https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: Yeah I did but after playing with the network I didn't fix it. I reinstalled Docker Toolbox and double checked that it works without doing anything special just using the default machine ip (`docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100`). But since DTB is deprecated I still need it to make it work on the new DfW.